# DocuSign envelope can be edited by any user

Tags: docusignapi

We were getting an error "Unable to access the envelope" if other user (not creator) was trying edit the envelope.

[old exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsZg6.png)

Now, we are not facing this exception and any user can edit the envelope. Is there any new change in behavior?

Comment: did you build an Oracle integration? how do you authenticate? can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any administrator user of the same account as well as the user that created the envelope should have access to that envelope.

This is by design. If you didn't have access before, it could be because it was a different user or the user had different access permission.